# Pure CSS tab using <a> as button

Tags: html, css

How do I do this? I want to change the content in my content area when a specific `<a>` tag is clicked. I am only limited to use HTML and CSS.

So far here are my codes:
HTML

```
<div class="content2">
    <div class="tabs-content"> 
        <p>Come in and experience...</p>
        <img id="imagecoffee" src="coffee.jpg" alt="Coffee Image">
        <ul>
            <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
            <li>Freshly made sandwiches</li>
            <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
            <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
            <li>Open mic nights </li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
        <p>23 Pine Road <br> Nottingham, NG1 5YU <br>0115 9324567 <br> <br> </p>        
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .content2 .tabs-content{
    display:none;
 }



.nav nav a:active ~ .tabs-content{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your full code,,,,there is `nav` or links in the HTML provided.

Answer (score 3):

You can use target tabs.

**CSS**

```
.tab div {
    display: none;
}

.tab div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tab">
    <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>   
    <div id="link1">
        <h3>Content to Link 1</h3>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This technique is described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_target_tab).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes